# Typescript Declaration Files for Local JS Files not by rootDirs

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
// Here is my file structure

src
 Foo
  index.js
typings
 Foo
 index.d.ts

package.json
tsconfig.json
```

how can i use type hinting in src/Foo/index.js

I had config rootDirs in tsconfg.json,and i want to know is here has other method to achieving the same effect